# copy jbehave stories into target directory using IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jbehave

Does anybody know how to configure IntelliJ Idea so that it automatically copies JBehave *.story files into the target directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`, add your extension to the list.